# How do I set a cookie that expires after a certain time using Tritium?

Tags: cookies, moovweb, tritium

I'd like to create a cookie that expires within 5 minutes of the user visiting my page.

I know about `add_cookie()` function, but have no idea how to set it to expire.

Answer (score 3):

You can set cookies in the `scripts/response_main.ts` file as such:

```
set_cookie("cookie_name", "cookie_val")
cookie("cookie_name") {
  cookie.expires("Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT")
}
```

Check out [this link](https://console.moovweb.com/learn/docs/local/configuration/cookies) for more info.

Comment: Aye @GiovanniAnthonyBrydenJr. you gotta mark my answer as correct